# How to use orderByRaw correctly in laravel's eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

So I am trying a few complex ordering filters in Eloquent. So I have a patent_text table. Here is the migration table for it:

```
        Schema::create('patent_text', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('patent_id')->unsigned()->index('patent_id');
            $table->enum('text_type', array('ICLAIM', 'CLAIM', 'DESCRIPTION', 'ABSTRACT', 'TITLE'))->nullable();
            $table->enum('type', array('ORIGINAL', 'MACHINE'))->nullable();
            $table->string('language', 2)->nullable();
            $table->longText('text')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('patent_id',
                'patent_text_ibfk_1')->references('id')->on('patent')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');

        });
```

So now I am trying to order by `text_type` and I want to have `ORIGINAL` first and then `MACHINE` but that is easy.

I just do `$this->texts->orderBy('text_type');` and it works just fine. The `ORIGINAL` texts are put first and then the other ones.

But I also want to order by the language field. I want `en` to be on top and then others. So I tried `orderByRaw` like so:

```
$this->texts()->orderBy('text_type')->orderByRaw("FIELD(language , 'en', 'se') ASC")->get()
```

But it did not work and I cannot figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Try like as `orderByRaw("CASE WHEN language =  'en'
THEN 0 
WHEN language =  'se'
THEN 0 
ELSE 1 
END")`

Comment: Works like a charm. Please post an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `orderByRaw` along with `CASE` instead of `FIELD` like as

```
->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN language = 'en' THEN 0 WHEN language = 'se' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END")
```